# Is it a bad idea to use the same function as event for different controls?

Tags: c#, winforms

### An example:

```cs
private void ListViewGeneric_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```

And assign this function as event function for ListView1, ListView2, ListView3:

```
this.ListView1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.ListViewGeneric_DragEnter)
this.ListView2.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.ListViewGeneric_DragEnter)
this.ListView3.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.ListViewGeneric_DragEnter)
```

### Another example:

```
private void ListViewGeneric_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;

    System.Drawing.Point cp = listView.PointToClient(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y));
    ListViewItem dragToItem = listView.GetItemAt(cp.X, cp.Y);
    if (dragToItem != null)
    {
        int dropIndex = dragToItem.Index;
        MoveListItem(listView, listView.FocusedItem.Index, dropIndex);
    }
}
```

And do the same for `DragDropEventHandler` ?

In this case I can use `sender` to know which control called the function. Is it a bad idea? Is there something that will go bad, or became unpredictable, ambiguos?

Comment: That's totally OK. If you want to handle events in same way, it's OK to use same handler

Comment: Go for it. There's a reason every event handler accepts the sender as its first argument.

Comment: Unless the functions are same for the controls, it's totally fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's perfectly fine.

What you don't want to do is start with

```
if (sender == control1) { ... }
else if (sender == control2) { ... }
...
```

It's also important to name the handler in an appropriate way indicative of handling events for more than one control (you've done a good job of this).

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer: if you need the same functionality for multiple controls, then use the one method many times. If each control needs different functionality, then use many methods, not `if (control1 ..)` approach. Nice answer.